# slideTo method doesn't work in swiperjs - nuxt-swiper library

Tags: nuxt.js, swiper.js

I am making a slider using `swiper.js` in nuxt project`(nuxt-swiper library)` that has a `thumbnail gallery`

and I want the top slider to change to the desired slide when I click on any of the photos in the thumbnail gallery(my slideto method), but the swiper slideTo`(in my slideto method)` method doesn't work.

```
<template>

                  <Swiper 
                    class="text-xs w-full h-[90%]"    
                    :modules="[SwiperEffectCreative]"    
                    :slides-per-view="1"   
                    grab-cursor  
                    :loop="true"
                    @swiper="onSwiper" >
                      <SwiperSlide v-for="(img, index) in images" :key='index'>
                        <img src="@/assets/images/products/p4.png" />
                      </SwiperSlide>

                  </Swiper>
                  <div class="flex flex-row w-full h-[10%] bg-blue-300">
                    <div v-for="(img, index) in images" :key='index' >
                      <img @click="slideto" src="@/assets/images/products/p4.png" class="w-20 h-full"/>
                    </div>
                  </div>
</template>



<script>
  export default{
    setup(){
      let swiper = null,
          images = ref(['image1','image2','image3']);
      

      let onSwiper = (swiper)=>{
        swiper= swiper;
      }

      let slideto = ()=>{
        swiper.slideTo(2);
      }

      return{
        swiper,
        images,
        slideto,
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```